# Continuous map from lens space to $S^1$ is null-homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Does any map from lens space L to a circle is null-homotopic?

Since the fundamental group of lens space is just $Z_m$, at least $f_*\pi _1(L)$ is trivial. And we can lift f to covering space $S^{2n-1}$. So can we have further results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $L$ is some lens space, $f : L \to S^1$ a map, $f$ induces a homomorphism $f_* : \Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ at the level of fundamental groups. Any such homomorphism must be $0$, as $\Bbb Z$ has no torsion. Thus, $f$ lifts to a map $\tilde{f} : L \to \Bbb R$ to the universal cover, which is nullhomotopic by straightline homotopy. Push the homotopy downstairs to get a nullhomotopy of $f$.